# where is the __init function of ext4?

Tags: linux, filesystems, kernel

As every module that is to be inserted in the kernel needs an __init function. where can I find the __init function of the original ext4 module written by linus torvalds? I want to make some changes in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're looking for this method : https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/ext4/super.c#L5781

```
MODULE_ALIAS_FS("ext4");
.....
static int __init ext4_init_fs(void)
{
....
```

This `__init`method is the main one of the module because it is defined just after the official declaration `MODULE_ALIAS_FS("ext4")`which declares the `fs-ext4` module.

As mentioned by @MarkPlotnick, the `__init` and `__exit` methods are also referenced and published as the module entry/exit funcs with the [`module_init(ext4_init_fs)`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/ext4/super.c#L5859) call (and the next one for exit).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I would also appreciate it if you could tell me how did you pin point this function? There are a lot of __init functions for ext4 in the source code. and why I shouldn't make any changes to __init ext4_init_sysfs(void)?

Comment: @AvishekGhosh because this init is defined just after the `MODULE_ALIAS_FS("ext4");` official declaration of ext4 module

Comment: Also the fact that there's the macro call [module_init(ext4_init_fs)](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/fs/ext4/super.c#L5832), which expands to [two functions](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/module.h#L128) that make it the init function.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick right, I added this reference to my answer